# How do I create a python program that prints the numbers 1 to 10 in a random order?

Tags: python, random

I've recently learned how to use the random function after learning about loops and if statements. I was wondering how would I make it so that when I randomize 10 numbers, there wouldn't be and duplicates?

Comment: look for doc on `random.shuffle()`, it may be a bit disappointing, because it's already done for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You want [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```
import random
numbers = list(range(10))
random.shuffle(numbers)
print(numbers)
```